# Dynamically Assigning unique IDs to the Body tag of Pages using Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

In PHP there's a clever trick where, based on the URL of a page, you can automatically assign a unique ID to the body tag of every page on your site. (which i find super helpful in writing CSS).

e.g.

```
<?php
        $url = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $dir = $url[1] ? $url[1] : 'home';
?>

<body id="<?php echo $dir ?>">
```

-> source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/id-the-body-based-on-url/

The Result being that,

- a page with a url of "http://domain.tld/blog/home" gets a body with an ID of "blog", and
- a page with a url of "http://domain.tld" gets an ID of "home".

I'd like to know if there's an, (ideally) equally simple and elegant, way to do the same in a Ruby on Rails based website?

Thanks so much for sharing your wisdom, oh great mucky mucks of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could name it by controller and action by adding adding the following in application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :create_body_id
def create_body_id
  @body_id = "#{params[:controller]}-#{params[:action]}"
end
```

Then add this in the template: `id="<%= @body_id %>"`

For the index action in blog_controller you'd get `id="blog-index"`

Comment: thanks for your help. what exactly do you mean by, "For the index action in blog_controller you'd get class="blog-index" ? i.e. could you please relate these results to an example of a URL.

Comment: If you have not changed the routes and you have a controller called blog_controller and that controller has an action called index then the URL would be either of `/blog/` or `/blog/index/` and in both cases the body id (or class, I realize I used both in my example) would be `blog-index`.